# image replacement Struts 2

Tags: struts2, logic

hello
i want to develop an application in which six images can be upload by user and stored into the db and if user wants to enter an additional image, delete the oldest image(i.e the image which inserted first to db);plz give me useful logic, information &links for above stated probelm;
thanx in advance

Comment: by what t is related to the strut2.though your problem is not clear but i assume that it is more related to the logic.Is it not good to come up with your own solution and den ask for suggestion for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear. Anyway I am suggesting a solution from what I understand from your question.

You can use timestamp as a column in db table and use min function to find the row with oldest timestamp. Then update that row's file name and timestamp with new file name and current timestamp. I think this will solve your problem